# If Blogger Menu Search Labels URLs blocked by Robots, Do I lose Pagerank?

Tags: seo, blogger

I have about 50 Search Labels links (domain.com/search/label/....)  on my blogger menu with rel="noindex".

~50 links like that in the menu:
`<a href='/search/label/Category?max-results=20' itemprop='url' rel='noindex' title='Category'>`

My blogger is using the default robots.txt:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow: 

User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Allow: /
```

The default blogger robots.txt file is blocking the search labels URLs from search bots in order to avoid them being indexed.
Do I lose potential Page Rank that way?

Comment: There is not enough here to fully answer your question. For example, are these the only page linked? If not and you link to product and possibly category pages, then 50 out of ??? should not really make a difference. What is important is that you create hierarchical linking from your home page through to all of your pages (as much as possible) from the most important to the least important. Each link from the home page represents importance so that just one link signals importance and several links signifies less importance. Navigation should contain only the very most important links.

Comment: @closetnoc thank you. ~40 search label links from about 100 total links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a PageRank perspective Google treats links to URLs in robots.txt the same way that it treats links with nofollow:  it drops the PageRank that would usually go to that link.   So in your case it doesn't matter what you do.   Either way Google is going to drop the PageRank.

From a practical standpoint this doesn't matter.  Having links that drop PageRank doesn't hurt the rankings of the linking pages.   It doesn't matter if you have two nofollow links on those pages or 100, Google doesn't change how they rank.   I've tested this.   I've tried removing large lists of nofollowed links from pages to improving rankings.   It just doesn't help.

My guess is that Google uses a domain authority signal much more prominently in its algorithm that it has ever disclosed.     Bleeding PageRank ends up not mattering when domain authority is so important.

Using nofollow on internal links is a PageRank sculpting technique that was popular 10 years ago.   It has fallen out of fashion because it doesn't appear to work anymore.   At this point, I would recommend only using nofollow on external links that are ads or user generated content.